# How do you use division in LaTeX to adjust parameters?

Tags: graphics, pgfmath

I would like to define a macro that draw a triangle nested in a triangle.  I already have a triangle macro using `TikZ` that draws a nice triangle given a size.  For simplicity,

```
\tr{4}
```

Will create a triangle of size 4.  What I would like is a macro for nested triangles that calls tr twice, once with the size, and then again with half the size.

```
\newcommand{\trNest}[1]{\tr{#1} \tr{ {#1} / 2}}
```

There is just one thing, `/` does not perform division.  How can I pass the result of dividing argument by a number in LaTeX?

Comment: Would be nice if you created a minimal example with the `\tr` macro you've defined.

Comment: Have you tried `\tr{\numexpr #1/2\relax}`?

Comment: Depending on how you defined the `\tr` macro (and hence would be good to have a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) as per @TorbjørnT.'s comment), you could just use tikz's `scale = 0.5` option, or use `0.5*#1` (with the `calc` package), or use `pgfmath`/`\pgfmathsetmacro` to perform numerical computation.

Comment: @Peter Grill.  Your answer of using 0.5*_ works great.  Thank you!

Comment: @Torbjorn T.  I am confused.  What would you like to see?  I can upload the macro I used, if that would help.

Comment: Generally (there are exceptions) it is always nice if produce a so called minimal working example, or MWE (follow the link in Peter's answer). In your case that could be as simple as `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz} \newcommand\tr[1]{<your macro definition>}\begin{document}\tr{4}\end{document}`. Such examples makes it easier to find solutions that work, not having to make any guesses about how your setup is. Of course, as demonstrated by Peter, working solutions can in some cases be found without such examples, but it general it is nice to have.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you defined the `\tr` macro, there are different options that could be employed including:

- tikz's `scale = 0.5` option, or
- use `x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm` to change the `x` and `y` unit vectors, or
- use `0.5*#1` (with the calc package), or
- use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to perform numerical computation.

Which one makes more sense would depend on the specifics of the `\tr` macro, and hence would be good to have a MWE as requested in the comments.